# Can't seem to get to the src= to compare image filenames in MonkeyScript

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, src

My function is as follows:

```
function mySound() {                                        
var eventTable = document.querySelector("#eventContent"); 
var eventCella=eventTable.getElementsByClassName("ago_eventlist_activity"); 
 var eventCellb = eventTable.getElementsByClassName("missionFleet");

for (var i = 0; i < eventTable.rows.length-1; i++) { 
var cella = eventCella[i]; 
var cellb = eventCellb[i];
if (cella.src == "Activity15.gif" && cellb.src == "60a018ae3104b4c7e5af8b2bde5aee.gif") 
{theSound = probeSound; oaPlaySound();}
if (cella.img == "Activity15.gif" && cellb.img == "cd360bccfc35b10966323c56ca8aac.gif") 
{theSound = attackSound; oaPlaySound();}
            if (cella.img == "Activity15.gif" && cellb.img == "575dfbbe877f58d6c09120ffbcaabe.gif") {theSound = attackSoundRIP; oaPlaySound();}
     }  /* for i  */
}
```

*I can't use ...byid cause it doesn't seem to have one?
I am including a link to the FireFox inspect element so you can see what I can see to try to make this work.

Image of InspectElement:

[image: Image of InspectElement]

Any help would be helpful I am just trying to code this for a friend and I really don't know java at all.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between Java and javascript. I'm guessing you mean javascript since that is what the code appears to be.

There are a few issues with the code

- `cella.img` does not target the image inside of the cell, you'll need to target the image first, or use find the image inside the cell.

  ```
  var eventCella = eventTable.querySelector(".missionFleet img");
  ```

  or

  ```
  var imgb = eventCellb[i].querySelector("img");
  ```
- Does the `ago_eventlist_activity` cell even contain an image? There doesn't seem to be one in the screenshot.
- Checking the image `src` needs to include the complete url, unless you use an `indexOf`...

  ```
  if (imgb.src.indexOf('60a018ae3104b4c7e5af8b2bde5aee.gif') > -1) {
     // do something
  }
  ```

I hope that helps. Please, the next time you ask a question, include the HTML instead of a screenshot. Or better yet, include a demo (jsFiddle) that shows the problem because it makes it easier for others to help. Not everyone will take the time or make an effort.

Comment: Ok, yes ago_evetlist_activity does contain a img src also it is position 0 of the table/row the other is in position 3 of the row(if they are present(They are not always there) if the ago_eventlist_activity is present then one of the other 3 will be in position 3 of the same row. Depending on the missionFleet img src will select the sound that I need to play- At least that is what I am trying to accomplish.  I appreciate the input and I will experiment from what you provided. One question you said the src would have to match the entire url?

Comment: In the code that I am modifying it seems only the filename w/o even the .gif was being used? So there must be a way to shorten it to just the file name itself?

Comment: UpDate: I used the:> var imga = eventCella[i].querySelector("img");< In the loop and  I inserted alerts to see where and it causes it to fail the rest of the code doesn't execute.

Comment: Here is the image of the ago_eventlist_activity so you can see it has a img https://gyazo.com/6c51f73fd1c095845ef8195f64ffa567

Comment: If you use `src.indexOf()` you do not need to use the entire url, just the file name should be enough. If the image isn't always there, you'll need to make sure that doesn't cause an error in the javascript.... something like `if (imgb && imgb.src.indexOf(...) > -1)`

Comment: src.indexOf() causes a syntax_exception error and stops the script in it's tracks: In the [table] column 0 & 3 may have an img- 3 will always but 0 is the problem sometimes it does and sometimes it has text or something else. I have looked at many solutions and all cause the same error- there has to be a way to test if there is an img with out causing an exception error.  I have tried like 20 different ways and am getting really frustrated lol. The weird thing is that I can check for img in pos(3) even when the table is empty and "not" get the error- and that makes no sense to me?

Comment: Please provide some HTML examples.

Comment: When I used the scr.indexOf as above it stopped so I used the following: function GetFilename(url)
{
   if (url)
   {
      var m = url.toString().match(/.*\/(.+?)\./);
      if (m && m.length > 1)
      {
         return m[1];
      }
   }
   return "";